# Find $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{2\pi\cos^{2n}(\theta)} \ n=1,2,3,\dots$ via Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

So the question is as follows: Use the Residue Theorem to calculate $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi\cos^{2n}(\theta)} d\theta \quad\quad n=1,2,3,\dots.$$
Now I believe the first step would be to use the fact $\cos(\theta)=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}=\frac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{2},$ $d\theta=\frac{-i}{z}dz$ and that $$\frac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{2}\Longrightarrow z^2+1=0 \Longrightarrow (z+i)(z-i)=0,$$
to get
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi\cos^{2n}(\theta)}=\frac{-i(2^{2n})}{2\pi}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z(z+i)^{2n}(z-i)^{2n}}.$$
Now this has poles at the points $z=0,i,-i,$ but $i$ and $-i$ are on the contour and so can we can't use the Residue Theorem right? I'm just not sure if I am on the correct path or not. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The original integral has a non-integrable singularity at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, so it makes no sense unless you take its principal value. Are you sure you wasn't asked to compute the integral of $\cos(\theta)^{2n}$, instead?

Comment: So that is the question, but it didn't specify only positive $n$ and so I read that as meaning to do both. If you don't mind me asking how can we justify that $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is non-integrable?

Comment: $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a simple zero for the cosine function, hence $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a pole of order $2n$ for the integrand function. You wrote $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ so I guess we are dealing with a non-converging integral.

Comment: I think the question is to compute for arbitrary $n=1,2,3,...$, not taking the limit.

Comment: Correct, we should do it for any $n$ or at least that is how I have been interpreting it.